# How to add Security Headers in Vue App running on tomcat

Tags: vue.js, security, tomcat

I have a vue app that is deployed on server running a tomcat 9. HOw can I add Feature-Policy and Expect-CT headers to all the pages?

Comment: Hello, could you solve it?

I only found the way to do it on Apache webserver but not Apache Tomcat

Comment: Hello @Andres
Yes I was able to go around it. What I did was I created a custom servlet filter and added that in the tomcat configuration for the relevant path.

Comment: Great @Rachit, can you post please the example of custom servlet filter?. Maybe it can be of great help to others who have the same problem and this post could be marked as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Andres added the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter class that add headers to response

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyCustomHeadersFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
} 

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    HeaderResponseWrapper headerResponseWrapper = new HeaderResponseWrapper(httpResp);

    headerResponseWrapper.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    headerResponseWrapper.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    headerResponseWrapper.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.

    chain.doFilter(request, headerResponseWrapper);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

HeaderResponseWrapper class

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HeaderResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
private CharArrayWriter writer;
  
public HeaderResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
    writer = new CharArrayWriter();
}
  
public PrintWriter getWriter() {
    return new PrintWriter(writer);
}
  
public String toString() {
    return writer.toString();
}
}
```

Now add this class as filter in the web.xml of tomcat and map it to relevant URLs

```
<filter>
<filter-name>MyCustomHeadersFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.headers.config.MyCustomHeadersFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>MyCustomHeadersFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```